# Getting empty array when pass data from php to JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is my code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var obj=[]  ;
    function getData(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'jqueryJsonTest.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            success:function(data){
            obj = data ; 
            alert ("alert 1: "+obj.length);
            }
        });
        }

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
    alert("alert 2: "+obj.length);
    alert("alert 3: "+obj.length);
});

</script>
```

Why is the first result after saving data an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an *asynchronous AJAX call* which returns immediately. It returns before the `success` callback is executed (where you are setting `obj` to whats returned). What you should do is do further processing in the `success` handler - OR - making your ajax call synchronous using `async: false` option (not recommended)

Try passing the callback handler to your `getData()` function. i.e. something like:

```
function getData(mycallback){
    $.ajax({
        url:'jqueryJsonTest.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        success:function(data){
            mycallback(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData(function(obj) {
        alert("alert 2: "+obj.length);
        alert("alert 3: "+obj.length);
    });
});
```